# Вопрос по эмодзи в Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Что я делаю не так, в чём ошибка?

```
message = "Погода"
if message == "\ud83c\udf25Погода":
weather()
```

Но тут ошибка и он не понимает что я отправил эмодзи.

Comment: соблюдайте отступы

Comment: Отступы у меня в коде есть.

Comment: в таком случае вы сравниваете разные вещи, почему нельзя сравнить так:`message = "\ud83c\udf25Погода"
if message == "\ud83c\udf25Погода":`

Comment: Проблема в том что боту я отправляю не юникод, а именно эмодзи.

Comment: В любом случае надо привести все к одному виду

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: есть подозрение что так `if message == "Погода"`